# Decline to sign document voids it for others

Tags: docusignapi

I sent a document for sign to multiple users using DocuSign API. One of the user declined to sign the document show a message :

> "If you decline, the document will be voided for all the other signers
>   and they will not be able to access it".

I want to know if this a
default behavior or something related to settings in my account as I
do not what the document to be voided it any of the one user declines
to sign it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the designed behavior for a decline button.

It sounds like a decline button is not what you want to use in your workflow if you don't want it voided.